# How to merge and sum up certain values of items that have the same ID value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So i have 2 tables. `Orders` and `OrderItems`. Relationship is each Order can have many OrderItems (orderitem is just a product).

OrderItem Table

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY
name TEXT
quantity INT
pack_value INT
order_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ORDER_ID ON ORDERS TABLE
product_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PRODUCT_ID ON PRODUCTS TABLE
```

Orders Table

```
order_id INT PRIMARY KEY
status TEXT
user_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES USER_ID ON USERS TABLE
```

An order can have the same OrderItem twice or only once. For example like below, 3 items but 2 products:

```
OrderItem(id=1, product_id=100, name="Pizza", quantity=2, pack_value=10, order_id=7)
OrderItem(id=2, product_id=100, name="Pizza", quantity=10, pack_value=1, order_id=7)
OrderItem(id=3, product_id=555, name="Olives", quantity=5, pack_value=1, order_id=7)
```

So above there is 2 entries for `Pizza` and this is the result i get. However i want it to only show 1 entry for `Pizza` because its the same item. Below is what i want to see:

```
OrderItem(product_id=100, name="Pizza", quantity=30, pack_value=1, order_id=7)
OrderItem(product_id=555, name="Olives", quantity=5, pack_value=1, order_id=7)
```

So essentially, if the item only exists once, then do nothing to it. If it exists twice, then make the `pack_value=1` and the quantity is the sum of the individual `quantity*pack_value`. So in example above quantity becomes `(2*10 + 10*1 = 30)`.

The controller method is like below, and so here is where I want to do this:

```
public function showOrderDetails(Order $order){
    return view('orders.show', compact('order'));
}
```

Also the `Order` and `OrderItem` models has the method for the relationships. For example, in the Order Model i have:

```
public function orderItems(){
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class, 'order_id');
}
```

Thanks, and if you need any extra info i can provide.

Comment: share db fiddle fo the same

Comment: @aRvi https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8jCGWdx4SCHKChczazzJfV/0

Comment: there is no `pack_value` in fiddle, and insert sample data that you have mentioned

Comment: *Below is what i want to see* Explain how `quantity=2` and `quantity=10` were collapsed to `quantity=30`...

Comment: @Akina `(2*10 + 10*1 = 30)` When 2 items are the same it is the sum of `quantity*pack_value` for each item. The value can be either 1 (sold as single) or more than one (multipack value)

Comment: Do you mead that combined row ALWAYS have `pack_value=1`?

Comment: Yes thats correct, combined has 1 @Akina

Comment: Iа so then simply group by `order_id` and `product_id`, calculate `quantity` as `SUM(quantity*pack_value)` and set `pack_value=1`.

Comment: @aRvi This is the updated fiddle with data inserted. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iQNJsQrEajHpib1UyxorS2/1

Comment: @Akina Could you possibly give an example, as i dont quite understand that? I have linked the previous comment with the db fiddle and some data inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name, 
       SUM(quantity * pack_value) AS quantity,
       1 AS pack_value,
       order_id
FROM order_items
GROUP BY name,
         order_id;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iQNJsQrEajHpib1UyxorS2/2)

Merge another tables to this code using it as subquery, or add them into FROM clause (adjusting its output list and grouping expression) if needed.

Comment: Perfect. That is nice, and thanks for the example.I never knew this stuff was possible with SQL, for the past day i was trying to do with php. I will have to learn more of this. Much appreciated!